# Pointer to a local variable survives

Tags: c, pointers

I'd like to ask a simple question. Please, consider the attached code. In the main function, a pointer to a struct is built in two different ways by means of either ctor1 or ctor 2. In both cases the program works no matter which constructor I use.

The reason why ctor1 works is that memory for struct instance is allocated outside the function frame (i.e. in the heap). Therefore, it will be available in the main function after ctor1 termination.

My question boils down to ctor2 function. As far as I know, the local variable "myPtr foo" is expected to be destroyed at the function end. Hence, "that" pointer should point to nothing from now on. Having executed the program however, I found out that both constructors work flawlessly.

Obviously, there is a subtle detail that eludes me. Could you explain why function ctor2 works?
Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int _method(void) {

    return 0;
}//_foo

typedef struct vTable {
    int (*method)(void);
} myPtr;

myPtr *ctor1(void) {
myPtr *foo;

    foo = (myPtr*)malloc(1 * sizeof(myPtr));
    foo->method = &_method;

    return foo;
}//ctor1

void ctor2(myPtr *that) {
myPtr foo = { &_method };

    that = &foo;

    return;
// having reached the function end "foo" is destroyed
// and "that" should point to nothing, supposedly
}//ctor2

int dtor(myPtr *foo) {

    free(foo);
    foo->method = NULL;
    foo = NULL;

    return 0;
}//dtor

int main(void) {
myPtr *vPtr;

    // it works as expected
    vPtr = ctor1();
    printf("%p\n\n", vPtr); // 003E0F68
    dtor(vPtr);

    // it works surprisingly enough
    ctor2(vPtr);
    printf("%p\n", vPtr); // 003E0F68
    printf("%p\n", vPtr); // 003E0F68
    // it keeps on working
    printf("%p\n", vPtr); // 003E0F68
    dtor(vPtr);

    return 0;
}//main
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIa1q.png)

Comment: Using a pointer to a destroyed object is undefined behavior. If it seems to work, it's just by accident, possibly because the memory hasn't been reused yet.

Comment: The `ctor2` function *doesn't* work, for one reason that's not about pointing to local variables: You pass the pointer to the function *by value*. You only modify the *local variable* `that` inside the function. The `vPtr` variable in the `main` function is not modified at all.

Comment: `free(foo);    foo->method = NULL;` causes undefined behaviour. You can not attempt to modify an object after freeing it

Comment: Thanks for responses. Similar technique is used by Quantum Leaps in this article, page 8.

https://www.state-machine.com/doc/AN_OOP_in_C.pdf

I was wondering if it is legal.

Comment: @user3633207: The code in that article passes a pointer to a structure containing `vptr`, which is then modified. Assigning a value to `vptr` in **object you are pointing to** changes the `vptr` member of the object. Your code passes `vptr` in a parameter. Changing a parameter changes only the parameter, which is a **copy** of the passed value.

Answer (score 1):

The code `void ctor2(myPtr *that)` declares `that` to be a parameter that points to an object of type `myPtr`. Parameters are passed by value, so the parameter `that` is only a copy of whatever was passed. Changing `that` does not change the thing that was passed.

If you want to change the value of a pointer to `myPtr`, you must pass a pointer to a pointer to `myPtr`:

```
void ctor2(myPtr **that)
```

Then you can change it with:

```
*that = malloc(…);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here, let's go through them one by one.

First, in your `ctor2` function:

```
void ctor2(myPtr *that) {
    myPtr foo = { &_method };
    that = &foo;
    return;
}//ctor2
```

This function is actually taking in a pointer to myPtr by value and modifying it locally to point to something allocated on the stack in the function. This has on effect on the pointer passed in. If you wanted to modify the pointer passed in, you would have passed in a double pointer and dereference it:

```
void ctor2(myPtr **that) {
    //malloc foo
    *that = foo;
    return;
}
```

Secondly, because you never modified vPtr through the call to `ctor2` the second call to `dtor` is freeing already freed memory, which is undefined behavior that usually leads to a crash. I'm surprised it didn't crash on your system, but that's the thing with UB, you never know.

Thirdly, the behavior you wanted to emulate is:

```
/* constructor */
void Shape_ctor(Shape * const me, int16_t x, int16_t y) {
  static struct ShapeVtbl const vtbl = { /* vtbl of the Shape class */
    &Shape_area_,
    &Shape_draw_
  };
  me->vptr = &vtbl; /* "hook" the vptr to the vtbl */
  me->x = x;
  me->y = y;
}
```

The difference is that in this case the `ShapeVtbl` structure is statically allocated. This is OK because it only points to functions, which will not change from object instance to object instance. But having it statically allocated allows it to be allocated within a function like that and assigned to the object.

Comment: Thanks! This rundown was helpful, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

To amplify Eric Postpischil's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455388/451601), consider,

```
void foo( int i ) { i++; }
```

This function changes the value it was passed, but not that value is a copy of the original when it was invoked,

```
int j=8; 
foo(j);
```

You wouldn't expect `j` to change, right?

The same is true for

```
void ctor2(myPtr *that) { // my version
    that = NULL;
}
```

`that` is a copy of the parameter passed on invocation,

```
ctor2(vPtr);
```

Because `vPtr` doesn't change, your program prints ... its unchanged value.

`ctor2` can change the value of anything *pointed to* by `that`, but any change to the parameter itself has only a local effect.

There are other errors in your program, as other answers point out.  But the answer to why `ctor2` "works" is basically that it doesn't do anything.